# MySQL select row from one table with multiple rows in a second table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one table containing "Client" information, and another including "Payment" information for each client.

Simplified client table

```
client_id | client_name    | client_status
----------+----------------+--------------
1         | John St. Peter | In Arrears
2         | Peter St. John | Up-to-date
```

Simplified payments table

```
payment_id | client_id | payment_date | payment_amount
-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------
1          | 1         | 2017-12-12   | 123.45
2          | 2         | 2017-12-15   | 234.56
3          | 1         | 2017-12-17   | 23.45
4          | 1         | 2017-12-21   | 54.32
5          | 2         | 2017-12-23   | 34.56
```

With the above two tables, I want to produce a single table *with a single query* with all the pertinent information to generate a search grid where I can filter by any column in either of the two tables, namely, filter by "client_status" from "client" table, or "client_id" from "payments" table.

```
payment_id | client_id | client_name    | client_status | payment_date | payment_amount
-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+--------------+---------------
1          | 1         | John St. Peter | In Arrears    | 2017-12-12   | 123.45
2          | 2         | Peter St. John | Up-to-date    | 2017-12-15   | 234.56
3          | 1         | John St. Peter | In Arrears    | 2017-12-17   | 23.45
4          | 1         | John St. Peter | In Arrears    | 2017-12-21   | 54.32
5          | 2         | Peter St. John | Up-to-date    | 2017-12-23   | 34.56
```

So - in essence, I want to "duplicate records" in the clients table for as many times as necessary for corresponding records in the payments table to facilitate the search. I am using a premade grid tool (DataTables) which is used all over the system with a custom function made by the developer to generate the grid (so I don't want to mess with that function in fear of breaking the rest of the system), so a single query to get that data sounds like the more pragmatic approach. I also have an "Edit" feature for each row, which will edit the "client" table, and put a tabbed structure in the edit screen for the "payments" table, which currently works fine with two queries (one for the client, one getting all the payments for that client).

I have tried UNION as well as various JOIN statements (probably incorrect...), but either get syntax errors or a single result per "client" row, meaning it does not pick up in the filters.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question - I have searched, but could not find an answer that answers this scenario for me.

Comment: If you post your attempts at using 'JOIN' you should be close and get help in fixing them.

Comment: You want filter values from both tables combined basically  right?

Comment: SelakaN that is correct. So far @NappingRabbit seems to have a working answer. I never thought of using the two tables in one FROM. I kept playing with LEFT JOIN and UNION to no avail.

Comment: You can use nested select as well.pretty easier too

Comment: This is a very basic JOIN operation. Post your attemt using JOIN. There is not much you can do wrong. You probably just misunderstood the syntax.

Comment: I used a variant of this: "SELECT * FROM `clients` LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `clients`.`client_id` = `payments`.`client_id`" but I did not get the correct result then. I am getting a better result now, but I am not sure if it is exactly the same as I had it before. I have done many variants last night, none of them were successful. @PaulSpiegel, I ran more tests on the join above, and it works. Your comment got me to the answer, so please post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: As I understand, your attempt was correct. It's not clear what went wrong with your query  previously.  So actually you don't even have a question that I can answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

here is a join...

```
select *
from clientsTable c,
     paymentsTable p
where c.client_id = p.client_id
order by p.payment_id;
```

that should give you everything.

edit:  for empties...  payments with no clients...

```
select *
from clientsTable c,
     paymentsTable p
where c.client_id = p.client_id 
   or p.client_id = null
order by p.payment_id;
```

Comment: Wow - that was fast, and also appears to be working! Thank you - I want to implement, then will mark as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: it will not as it is written.

Comment: Yeah - I just picked that up. So - cannot mark this as correct. Can you adjust your answer, @NappingRabbit?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel commented on my original question, and I feel really silly, because that is a very simple query - and it works. I had no internet last night, so I could not really research why it did not work.

Comment: so you want clients with no payments and payments with no clients also?